# std::is_same and std::get together

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming

I was trying to check if a specific type was into a typelist (a tuple). And ran into some troubles :

```
#include  <tuple>
#include  <iostream>

template < typename T >
struct Type {

  using type = T;
};

int main() {

  constexpr auto Foo = std::make_tuple(Type<int>{},Type<int>{});
  if (std::is_same<int, std::get<0>(Foo)::type>::value)
    std::cout << "GG!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:47: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class, class> struct std::is_same’
   if (std::is_same<int, std::get<0>(Foo)::type>::value)
                                               ^
test.cpp:13:47: note:   expected a type, got ‘std::get<0ul, {Type<int>, Type<int>}>(Foo)’
```

Seems like `std::get` didn't show me the type like I wanted. Could someone explain me why?

Comment: `get` returns a value, not a type. Try to wrap the call to get in a `decltype` to find the type. Don't have a compiler I front of me to check atm though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::get<0>(Foo)::type` doesn't make any sense in this context, because `std::get<0>(Foo)` is a value, not a type.

Instead try this: we will use `decltype()` to obtain the type of that expression (without actually evaluating its value).  This will result in the `Type<int>&` type.  We'll use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) to remove the reference (because `Type<int>&::type` doesn't make sense either), and then we can access its `type` typedef.

It's a bit unwieldy, but it works:

```
if (
  std::is_same<
    int,

    // The decltype will be (Type<int>&). Decay to remove the
    // reference, cv-qualifiers, etc.
    std::decay< 
      decltype(std::get<0>(Foo))
    >::type::type
    // ^ Two ::types, one to extract the type from std::decay, one
    // for your Type<T> struct.
  >::value
) {
    std::cout << "GG!" << std::endl;
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/216c0921fd1b4dad))

There may certainly be better ways to accomplish this check, but this is one way.

Comment: Yes I hope I can do something better, I'm going to check Boost::Hana. Thanks to point this out :)

Comment: A shorter (or at least easier-to-grok) version would be `std::is_same<int, std::tuple_element<0, decltype(Foo)>::type::type>::value` but note that this depends on `Foo` being a tuple. The version in my answer should also work with `std::pair` and a few other types as well. Using `decltype` for as much of the expression as possible allows your templates to be more flexible.

Comment: This one is a little more readable, nice! Still going to check some library though. Anyway thanks!